# Using type refinement with function overloading in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```js
type FooBar = {
  (x: 'input-foo'): 'output-foo'
  (x: 'input-bar'): 'output-bar'
}

const foobar: FooBar = (x: 'input-foo' | 'input-bar') => {
  switch (x) {
    case 'input-foo': return 'output-foo'
    case 'input-bar': return 'output-bar'
  }
}
```

The code above gives the following error:

> Type `(x: 'input-foo' | 'input-bar') => "output-foo" | "output-bar"` is not assignable to type `FooBar`.

The association between input value and output value is being discarded. Is there any way to preserve this association in the type system?

Comment: I wrote an entire answer before successfully finding the place where I'd learned why this is and marking the duplicate. FWIW, [here's that answer](https://tsplay.dev/w26Jbw), but really Titian's the guy to listen to (in the linked question's answers).